# No puedo inicializar un ReportViewer en VS2017, pero en DataTools 2015 funciona correctamente

Tags: c#, windows-forms, reportviewer

He estado teniendo problemas con un reporte .rdl que he hecho en Data Tools 2015 en un proyecto de C# Windows Forms en VS2017. Siguiendo [esta guía](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-winforms-reportviewer-control) he logrado importar mi reporte a la aplicación y asociarlo a mi reportviewer, pero al iniciar el Form no aparece nada, ni siquiera un mensaje de error.

Este es el código que he estado manejando:

```
private void frmReportePrivado_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        LocalReport localReport = reportViewer1.LocalReport;
        localReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Soporte.ReporteAulasPrivadas.rdlc";
        localReport.ReportPath = "ReporteAulasPrivadas.rdlc";

        ReportParameter rpIDReporte = new ReportParameter();
        rpIDReporte.Name = "IDReporte";
        rpIDReporte.Values.Add(Conexion.IDReporte.ToString());

        // Set the report parameters for the report  
        localReport.SetParameters(
            new ReportParameter[] { rpIDReporte });

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Cuando lo inserto desde las propiedades del reportviewer si parece funcionar, pero me interesa hacerlo con recursos incrustados si es posible, y al parecer desde las propiedades tengo que declarar una dirección de archivo común para asociar el reportviewer al reporte.

EDIT: Creo que logré hacerlo funcionar usando las mismas propiedades del reportviewer y parece que ya funciona, pero ahora me marca el error **No se ha proporcionado ninguna instancia de origen de datos para el origen de datos DataSet1**. Yo tenía entendido que ese origen de datos ya venía incrustado en el mismo .rdl porque yo lo configuré desde ahí. ¿Qué es lo que tendría que poner en ese origen de datos? En el Data Tools solo coloque la cadena de conexión, ¿tendría que colocarla de nuevo dentro del código?

Comment: Tu pregunta es un misterio sin resolver. Llevo 6 meses buscando y consultando y al parecer hay incompatibiliadad con con la actualizacion de "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" a "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" pero nadie sabe??
Si tienes la solucion me comentas.
Saludos.
Jaime.

Comment: Hola Jaime, lo curioso es que un par de meses después lo hice funcionar perfectamente, pero poco tiempo después me interesó aplicarlo de nuevo de un entorno MUY similar y a pesar de replicar tanto el código como el modelo del reporte no logré hacerlo funcionar de nuevo. Si te interesa, esta noche puedo descargar mi proyecto donde lo hice funcionar para ver que fue lo que cambio con respecto a este código de ejemplo que tenía.